# shapely's scale function in geopandas returns points of similar magnitude

Tags: python, gis, scale, shapely, geopandas

I have a .shp file that I read into a geopandas dataframe. I change the coordinate reference system to 2163 since I'm making some rectangular maps and want them to look somewhat normal.

```
geo_df = geo.GeoDataFrame.from_file('path to shp files here')
geo_df = geo_df.to_crs(epsg=2163)
```

Dataframe looks like this:

```
In [10]: geo_df.geometry
Out[10]: 
0       POLYGON ((1189879.121395004 -1019103.847184072...
1       POLYGON ((1220434.289428635 -1303875.122589418...
2       POLYGON ((1210969.088787247 -1295221.772496042...
3       POLYGON ((1217371.162725744 -1300978.843646188...
```

Now I'm computing a pairwise distance matrix, but since these coordinates are given in meters, the numbers are quite large and I run into overflow problems. So I try this:

```
geo_df.geometry = geo_df.geometry.scale(xfact=1/10000, yfact=1/10000, zfact=1.0)
```

But the coordinates of my polygons are not any smaller (just shifted a bit, which is fine). Printing the supposedly rescaled dataframe gives this:

```
In [12]: geo_df.geometry.scale(xfact=1/10000, yfact=1/10000, zfact=1.0)
Out[12]: 
0       POLYGON ((1197230.99656014 -1026296.564074459,...
1       POLYGON ((1221475.564597901 -1304490.752661498...
2       POLYGON ((1215982.083961291 -1290526.930856638...
3       POLYGON ((1223839.012413891 -1292585.80012823,...
```

I was hoping to get something like this.

```
Out[12]: 
0       POLYGON ((119.723099656014 -102.6296564074459,...
1       POLYGON ((122.1475564597901 -130.4490752661498...
2       POLYGON ((121.5982083961291 -129.0526930856638...
3       POLYGON ((122.3839012413891 -129.258580012823,...
```

Maybe I just don't understand what [shapely's scaling function](http://toblerity.org/shapely/shapely.html) is supposed to do, though it seems pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scaling is defined relative to a center point. The scaling you applied actually did make the polygons smaller, but kept the center point at the center of the bounding box of the polygon. The `origin` keyword argument in `shapely.affinity.scale` defaults to the polygon center; to reduce the coordinate values by a factor of 10000, you can set `origin=(0, 0)`, as follows:

```
geo_df.geometry = geo_df.geometry.scale(xfact=1/10000, yfact=1/10000, zfact=1.0, origin=(0, 0))
```